# UITextView with HTML: How to display image in local

Tags: html, ios, image, uitextview, nsattributedstring

To display html in `uitextview`, I used NSAttributedString. It seems OK, except loading an image from local by `<img src=/var/mobile/Containers/...` is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// Save image in document
// Save path to imgPath
self.textContent = "<h1>Header</h1><h2>Subheader</h2><p>Some <em>text</em></p><img src='\(imgPath)' width=200 height=200 >"
if let htmlData = self.textContent.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    var attributedString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!
    self.txtView.attributedText = attributedString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
self.textContent = "<h1>Header</h1><h2>Subheader</h2><p>Some <em>text</em></p><img src="file:///var/mobile/....." width=200 height=200 >"
```

set image src start with "file://" may solve this problem.